# Why MapBox MGLMapView does not render map in a larger views?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I simply have UIView with frame for example 1600px x 2400px and I ma trying to add there as a subview `MGLMapView` with simple offset 20 px around. And it is not rendered totally, but only in the middle. Why?

This is how I setup my orange `wrapperView` with size mentioned above:

```
wrapperView.snp.updateConstraints { maker in
    maker.leading.top.equalToSuperview()
    maker.width.equalTo(size.width)
    maker.height.equalTo(size.height)
}
```

and then adding MGLMapView as a subview:

```
let url = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/mystaleexample")
let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: url)
wrapperView.addSubview(mapView)
mapView.backgroundColor = .magenta
mapView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
}
```

and this is what I receive on console:

> 2023-04-23 16:29:32.997918+0200 Territories[99901:9212504] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6
> 2023-04-23 16:29:33.020964+0200 Territories[99901:9212504] Failed to bind EAGLDrawable: <CAEAGLLayer: 0x281094330> to GL_RENDERBUFFER 1

And this is the effect for A1 vertical sheet size:

[image]

when for example for a3 and a4 is very correct:

[image]
[image]

Above images are simply create as a document PDFPage from snapshot for wrapperView above:

```
let document = PDFDocument()
let page = PDFPage(image: mainView.wrapperView.snapshot)!
document.insert(page, at: document.pageCount)
```

where snapshot is defined like:

```
extension UIView {
    var snapshot: UIImage {
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        
        drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```